# CSS display: block, animate H1.. jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to slideDown h2 using jQuery?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <hr>
    <h2>Text</h2>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("h2").slideDown();
});
```

not working

Comment: Hi LWWD, is my answer working out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Use `$(document).ready()` function.
2. First `hide()` the `h2` programmatically.
3. The `slideDown()`.

First `hide`, then `slideDown` and in `ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").hide().slideDown();
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h2").hide().slideDown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Text</h2>
```

Comment: Praveen you are always active ah ? :P

Comment: @YoYo Omg!!! Sorry... Will give you points when I see your good answers again. Don't worry! `:)`

Comment: hahaha ,,, its ok (y)  .. its good to learn from your answers

Comment: @YoYo Awesome. That's the spirit... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

To apply `slideDow` `h2` should be hidden. Try like below.

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    $("h2").slideDown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="display: none;">Text</h2>
```